# Is it possible to change the body content and path of a request in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-9

I'm currently trying to write a middleware to filter certain expressions from a request's path and content. I know it's possible to read the URI and raw body content using `$request->path()` and `$request->getContent()` respectively, but can't find a way to change it.

The code I have in mind would look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyMiddleware
{
  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    $uri = $request->path();
    $body_content = $request->getContent();
    $request->setContent(str_replace("foo","bar",$body_content));
    $request->setPath(str_replace("foo","bar",$uri));
    //functions setContent() and setPath() don't exist
    return $next($request);

}
```

Does Laravel have functions for this that I can't find, or if not, how would I go about this?

Comment: you can build a new request and set the content and path as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved this by creating a new request with the modified contents like this:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $uri = $request->path();
    $body_content = $request->getContent();
    //process $uri and $body_content here
    $final_request = Request::create($uri, $request->method(), $request->query->all(), $request->cookies->all(), $request->allFiles(), $request->server->all(), $body_content);
    return $next($final_request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify incoming request in middleware. In fact, your middleware can extend [`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php) class, that already have a bunch of useful methods to help you so. All you had to do is override `transform` method. You can see how it's done in [`ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php) middleware.

Comment: that adjusts the inputs in the input bag, not the actual body content

Comment: Nothing is stopping you to do so, just form a new request instance from string, but I'm not sure why you need it. Just modify prams you want  and use in controller ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.